# Java Vector: Each element contains three objects. How to operate based on the value of one of them?

Tags: java, vector, element

For example, I have `vector(object1, object2, price)`. How can I print elements where price > 100?

All the tutorials and documents (concerning operating in such way) I have seen only handle vectors where each element contains only one object.

So how can I get a handle on one specific object inside element? Or is this even possible?

A side question: what are those called? That is, if a single element is comprised of several items, what are those items called? Like in databases, a record is comprised of fields. Hard to google stuff you do not know the name of.

Main:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String type;
    String location;
    double value;

    System.out.print("type->");
    type=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("location->");
    location=sc.nextLine();

    Property prop=new Property(type,location);

    System.out.print("value->");
    value=sc.nextDouble();

    InsuranceInfo insu=new InsuranceInfo(prop,value);
    container.addInsuranceInfo(insu);
}
```

InsInfoContainer class:

```
public class InsInfoContainer {
    private Vector<InsuranceInfo> container;

    public InsInfoContainer() {
        container = new Vector<>(3, 1);
    }

    public void addInsuranceInfo(InsuranceInfo insu) {
        container.addElement(insu);
    }

public void print() {
        Iterator<InsuranceInfo> iter = container.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {System.out.println(iter.next());}
    }
```

InsuranceInfo class:

```
public class InsuranceInfo {
    public InsuranceInfo(Property prop, double value) {
        this.prop = prop;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private Property prop;
    private double value;

    public Property getProp() {return prop;}
    public void setProp(Property prop) {this.prop = prop;}
    public double getValue() {return value;}
    public void setValue(double value) {this.value= value;}
}
```

Property class:

```
public class Property {

    private String type;
    private String location;

    public Property(final String type, final String location) {
        this.type = type;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getType() {return this.type;}
    public void setType(final String type) {this.type = type;}
    public String getLocation() {return this.location;}
    public void setLocation(final String sijainti) {this.location = location;}
}
```

Comment: Please add your specific code you have a problem with so you can get better answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on posting. By the way, `Vector` is deprecated, use the [Java Collections framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) such as `List` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: I will be happy if I get a solution with some implementation of ArrayList, also. Or which keywords to google, or a link to where to find relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a container to store your `InsuranceInfo`:

`private Vector<InsuranceInfo> container;`

1. Your `container` is called `Collection`
2. Your `InsuranceInfo` instances inside your `container` are called `element`
3. Your "items" inside `InsuranceInfo` (`Property`, `value`) are called `property` or `field` of `element`

To iterate over your `container` collection, the usual ways are using `for` loop or `foreach` loop:

```
public void print() {
    for (InsuranceInfo element: container) {
       if (element.getValue() > 100) { // Here is your condition to filter elements
          // Process your elements here
       }
    }
}
```

You can also use `Iterator`, `Stream` to do that.